# MVC5 uploading a file to a online database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

So I'm doing a big project due on friday, but I'm having real issues now with uploading files to a database.

So far what I have achieved:

successfully adding the data to a Table on our database to show on our website,

the problem? The only way I get it to work is when you upload a file it saves it to your own computer in a local directory, since I want many people being able to upload the file I need to store it somewhere online, I was thinking github(Maybe they do not allow this), and then I would just store the anchor in our database and send that back when people want to download it.
    This works, but only stores it in your own PC:

```
var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Assets/Upload"), fileName);
```

this does not work, because  I Cannot convert System.Uri to String:

```
Uri baseUri = new Uri("http://www.github.com");
Uri myUri = new Uri(baseUri, "/***/Assets/Upload");
file.SaveAs(myUri);
```

And this piece of code compiles but when I run it and try to upload it I receive HttpException was unhandled by user code. Because it is not a valid virtual path:

```
string myUri = Server.MapPath("http://www.github.com/***/Assets/Upload");
```

I've tried more things, but alas not working. I've googled for hours without success. 
Any tips are welcome! I'm uploading a .srt file btw.

So my mission is this. You write a name of the file, description and pick a category, Then you choose which file to upload. Right now with the first code that you see on top of my question, the Path. things is: I choose a file, I press upload, I get a message that it went successful. There in my github team explorer I can open the folder Assets/upload but I end up in C:// blabla and there I see the file uploaded successfully. But i want to send it to a external server, online server. thats why I was trying Uri, but it doesnt allow me to save it there. :)

like this postimg.org/image/gxt6r13n3

Comment: When you upload a file it doesn't save anything to your local computer, that's a *download*, an upload sends the file data to the server. The server can then determine what to do with the file data... what are you trying to do? Can you explain what you want it to do in steps? It sounds like you are getting confused

Comment: I suggest you look at some tutorials that handle file upload.

Comment: @Charleh I added more information.

Comment: Still unclear on what you are trying to do - it sounds like you want to post a file from your local machine to an external server. You can't achieve this using any combination of `Server` methods, since the `Server` class relates to the web server (i.e. your machine or the host the application is running on in the case of a www hosted solution). The only way to get a file delivered to an external website is to consume their web API or to run an HTTP post to a page which will accept the file data. Can you add some further explanation? Are you hosting your solution or are you running it locally?

Comment: Also, I'm not familiar with github team explorer - doesn't this just browse a github repository? If so how would navigating anywhere in it get you to your local disk? I can't find anything on the net relating to it - do you mean Team Explorer in visual studio connected to a git repository?

Comment: @Charleh 
Yes you are correct! 100% I am sorry, Im not so good at explaining this, hehe. Im using team explorer in VS to conncet to git hub.

But yes you are right, im on my website, i choose a file, submit and I would like to store it on a external server. Would you be able to help me with this consuming web API, or how I Would let something accept my HTTP post data? also if you require to see some of my coding its no problem just let me know!

Im running my solution Locally but then I commit it to a github account.

Comment: I learned that doing a file stream and parse through the document would be a good idea, and store it in a table in our database, trying to implement that now :)